# C# struct and class variable value

Tags: c#, class, struct

i know that struct is of value type and class is reference type but when i execute the following code why im getting the two different answer

can any one explain a bit

```
[struct|class] values {
    public int x, y;

    public values (int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

values v = new values(12, 13);
object o = v;
v.x = 2;
Console.WriteLine(((values)o).x);
```

**Outputs**

when

1. it is class : output is   2
2. it is struct :output is   12

Can any one explain me?

Thanks

Comment: This is related to boxing and unboxing concept. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111857/why-do-we-need-boxing-and-unboxing-in-c).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The one line that behaves very differently for `struct` or `class` is

```
  object o = v;
```

- When `Values` is a reference type, `o` becomes a copy of the reference `v`. There still is only 1 instance of `Values`.
- When `Values` is a value type, `o` becomes a reference to the boxed copy of the instance itself. In this case the assignment creates a 2nd instance and you execute `v.x = 2` on the original. The copy is not affected.

Your example includes boxing and that is an unnecessary complication, when you use `values o = v;` you will get the same output. The line then creates a normal copy (2nd instance) without boxing.

To sum it up: the main difference between value and reference type is in *copy semantics*. You will notice different behaviour in simple assignments (`x = y`) and in parameter passing (`foo(x)`).

You can expect gotchas with mutable value types. As an exercise, see what `f.Myvalue.x = 2;` does with `Values` as class or struct with

```
 class Foo { public Values MyValue  { get; set; } }
```

Comment: Under what cases would `f.MyValue.X = 2;` even compile?

Comment: You're right, this won't compile. Consider it schematic for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a structure and you assign it (or use it as a parameter of a method), you have a brand new copy of your structure.
Whereas, with a class, you assign a reference to the class.

Answer (score 1):

Key line is

```
object o = v;
```

When values is struct (or value-type), it causes boxing values. According [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691158%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (following that link, you can find exactly your question at end :))

> Boxing a value of a value-type consists of allocating an object
>   instance and copying the value-type value into that instance.

So, your value in v is `copied`. When you unboxing here

```
Console.WriteLine(((values)o).x);
```

you get original `v` value, not `v` after

```
v.x = 2;
```

So, answer for struct (or value-types) is `12`.

For class (or reference-types) it's very simple. You are not boxing, just cast to object, so next you are working with this original `v` and change it value.

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
SomeStruct s1, s2, s3;
Object o1;
... s1 gets a value somehow, then...
s2 = s1;  // Q1
o1 = s1;  // Q2
s3 = (SomeStruct)o1; // Q3
```

statement Q1 will mutate structure `s2` by overwriting all of its public and private fields with the values of the corresponding fields in `s1`.  Statement Q2 will generate a new heap object which will act as though it contains a field of type `SomeStruct`, and will modify that field by overwriting all of its fields with the corresponding fields in `s1`.  Statement Q3 will check whether `o1` contains a "boxed" `SomeStruct` and, if so, will overwrite all the fields of `s3` with the corresponding ones from the boxed object.

Note that boxed structures are not *usually* modified while they sit within heap objects.  If one were to say:

```
var temp = (SomeStruct)o1;
temp.someField = Whatever;
o1 = temp;
```

that sequence would create a new heap object which would hold a modified copy of the original structure, but the original boxed structure would remain as it was.  There are, however, ways a structure within a boxed object can be modified.  One should in most cases avoid using such techniques, but one should be aware there's no such thing as a non-trivial immutable structure (a struct with no fields would be immutable, but not very useful).  In general, if one wants to be able to refer to a mutable instance of a structure type, it's best to encapsulate it within a simple class object, e.g.

```
class ExposedFieldHolder<T>
{
  public T Value; 
  public ExposedFieldHolder(T v) {Value = v;}
}
```

and if one wants to have an immutable instance, one should encapsulate it in an immutable class object

```
class ImmutableHolder<T>
{
  T value;
  public T Value { get { return value; } ; 
  public ImmutableHolder(T v) {value = v;}
  override public bool Equals(Object o) {
    var other = o as ImmutableHolder<T>;
    if (!other) return false;
    return Object.Equals(value,other.value);
  }
  override public int GetHashCode() { return Object.GetHashCode(value); }
}
```