# Boxing behavior difference in System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, boxing, expandoobject, unboxing

I recently started coding in C# and writing ASP.NET MVC apps. I was doing something similar to this:

```
var hashtable =  new Hashtable();
hashtable.Add("First", 12);
hashtable.Add("Second", 12);

if(hashtable["First"] == hashtable["Second"])
{
    Console.WriteLine("Equal");
}
else{
    Console.WriteLine("Not Equal");
}
```

It always outputs **`Not Equal`**. A while later I realized it was the effect of boxing. However, if I write the following:

```
var hashtable =  new Hashtable();
hashtable.Add("First", 12);
hashtable.Add("Second", 12);

dynamic ViewBag = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
ViewBag.hashtable = hashtable;

if(ViewBag.hashtable["First"] == ViewBag.hashtable["Second"])
{
    Console.WriteLine("Equal");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not Equal");
}
```

It always outputs **`Equal`**.

What is the underlying mechanism that is causing this difference?

Comment: "Equality is complicated.". This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273890/what-is-the-difference-between-and-equals-for-primitives-in-c

Comment: @AdrianNasui Thanks but I think the link you referenced is a different kind of problem. My confusion is not about reference equality vs value equality or implicity casting of short to int but what is causing `ViewBag.hashtable["First"]` to be automatically unboxed while `hashtable["First"]` is still boxed.

Comment: Sorry, gave it a bit more thought and I understood that your question is not about ref equality. Good question I am waiting for the answer.