# Should == operator behave exactly as Equals()?

Tags: c#, .net, operator-overloading, equals, iequatable

Let's consider `Polygon` class. Check for equality should compare references most of the time, but there are many situations where value equality comes in handy (like when one compares two polygons with `Assert.AreEqual`).

My idea is to make value equality somewhat secondary to reference equality. In this case it's pretty obvious that `==operator` should keep its default reference check implementation.

What about `object.Equals()` and `IEquatable<Polygon>.Equals()` then? MSDN doesn't imply that `==` and `.Equals()` should do the same but still - wouldn't it make the behavior of `Polygon` objects too ambiguous?

Also, the `Polygon` class is mutable.

Comment: they are not the same..`long story short` `.Equals used for object equality` `== used for checking equality of a value` do a google search for deeper clarification. why do people ask questions here that they can easily find the answer buy doing a simple google search `I'm just Curious`

Comment: I don't fault OP for asking this question here. I find that SO is a far more reputable source for informed answers than a Google search. And, as he says, MSDN is not always clear about these things.

Comment: @MikeHofer The question isn't *on topic* on SO.

Comment: See also related discussions at [Difference between Equals/equals and == operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/971954), [What is the difference between == and Equals() for primitives in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21273890), and [C# .Equals(), .ReferenceEquals() and == operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3869601) (those three are not exactly the same question, but the ample discussion in each does wind up addressing the question above as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147(v=vs.90).aspx) is almost clear about it

> To check for reference equality, use `ReferenceEquals`. **To check for
>   value equality, you should generally use `Equals`**. However, Equals as it
>   is implemented by `Object` just performs a reference identity check. It
>   is therefore important, when you call `Equals`, to verify whether the
>   type overrides it to provide value equality semantics. When you create
>   your own types, you should override `Equals`.

---

> **By default, the operator `==` tests for reference equality** by
>   determining if two references indicate the same object, **so reference
>   types do not need to implement operator ==** in order to gain this
>   functionality. **When a type is immutable**, meaning the data contained in
>   the instance cannot be changed, **overloading operator == to compare
>   value equality instead of reference equality can be useful** because, as
>   immutable objects, they can be considered the same as long as they
>   have the same value. **Overriding operator `==` in non-immutable types is
>   not recommended**.

[IEquatable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation is also very clear

> Defines a generalized method that a value type or class implements to
>   **create a type-specific method for determining equality of instances**.

Comment: I don't want to override `==`. I'm asking whether overriding `.Equals()` (to make it compare by value) in a mutable class doesn't introduce ambiguity. And considering that value equality check is ideologically "secondary" to reference check.

Answer (score 1):

A major difficulty with equality testing in .NET (and also Java) is that there are two useful equivalence relations, each based on a question that can be sensibly asked of any class object, but .NET isn't consistent about which question or relationship should be encapsulated by `Equals` and `GetHashCode` supposed to answer.  The questions are:

1. Will you always and forever be equivalent to the object identified by some particular reference, no matter what happens to you.
2. Will you consider yourself equivalent to the object identified by some particular reference unless or until something with a reference to you does something that would affect that equivalence.

For immutable objects, both relationships should test value equality.  For mutable objects, the first question should test referential equivalence and the second should test value equality.  For an immutable object which holds a reference to an object which is of mutable type, but which nobody will ever mutate, both questions should test value equality of that encapsulated object.

My personal recommendation would be that mutable objects not override Object.Equals, but that they provide a static property that returns an `IEqualityComparer` which tests value equality.  This would require that
any object that immutably encapsulates the mutable object will have to
get that `IEqualityComparer` to be able to report the encapsulated object's
value-equivalence relation as its own, but having an `IEqualityComparer`
would make it possible to store such things in e.g. a `Dictionary` provided
they are never modified.