# Why does 10.Equals(10f) result in false while 10 == 10f results in true?

Tags: c#

`10.Equals(10f)` result in `false` while `10 == 10f` results in `true`. Latter is because when comparing an `int` with a `float` the `int` is converted to `float`. I just don't understand why `int.Equals` obviously does not convert the `int` value into `float` if the passed object is a `float` object.

This in my opinion is a problem with constant matching, when assuming that `variable == constant` is identical to `variable is constant`. If the variable is of type `object`, for example following matching fails:

```
object value = 10f;
if (value is 10)
{
    // This block is not run
}
```

I would not expect this match to fail. So, why is it that `10.Equals(10f)` result in `false`?

Comment: See [C# Equals() == about number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46884638/c-sharp-equals-about-number).

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.equals?view=netcore-3.1#System_Int32_Equals_System_Object_) the part *"Note to callers"*

Comment: Thanks for the info. Still confusing with constant pattern matching, but that's how it is I assume.