# C# int equality operator unexpectedly false

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

This is a more broad question, with my specific example. The code that gets to this point is rather convoluted so I hope this is enough.

Under what circumstances in C# are two of the same ints not equal?

```
1005 == 1005 //false
```

[image]

[image]

`specConversion` started off as a passed string `spec`, where the type of `y` (a property on a class) was determined, and then `spec` was converted to that type as `specConversion`. This appears to be working as intended, as both vars have the same type at this point. I'm not certain any of that is even relevant to the initial question: why are these two int values not equal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between == and Equals() for primitives in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273890/what-is-the-difference-between-and-equals-for-primitives-in-c)

Answer (score 8):

When the debugger displays this:

```
object {int}
```

that means it's an int that is [boxed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing). A boxed value type is an `object` (specifically, a [System.ValueType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype?view=net-6.0)), which is a reference type. Each boxing results in a new object instance, meaning that they will not have [reference equality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/equality-comparisons#:%7E:text=Reference%20equality%20means%20that%20two,shown%20in%20the%20following%20example.&text=In%20this%20code%2C%20two%20objects,refer%20to%20the%20same%20object.), even if they have boxed the same value. The `==` operator, for reference types, tests reference equality, so in this case it will return false.

If you want value equality instead of reference equality, use `Equals`.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        object a = 1;
        object b = 1;

        Console.WriteLine(a == b);
        Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/eSuFVL

The other solution is to store your `int` values in actual `int` variables instead of objects, e.g. by using [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77632/what-is-cool-about-generics-why-use-them).

Comment: +1.  Might be worth pointing out that the debugger will display `object {int}` only in boxing scenarios.  (or some weird override of `.ToString`)