# how to parse data from array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, object, indexing, sqldatareader

I got ienumerable method which I read data from database and this data i put in array of object

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    var values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
    reader.GetValues(values);
    yield return values;
}
```

And in another method i'm iterating these objects

```
foreach (var items in repo.ExecuteReader()
   {
        rss.Id = items[0]; // not work
        yield return items;
   }
```

How can I indexing there array of 'items'?

Comment: What s the type of `Items`? is it `object[]` ?

Comment: What do you mean with "// not work"?

Comment: @Hari Yes, public IEnumerable<object> ExecuteReader()

Comment: @TimBourguignon,  
It says that: "cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'"

Comment: Use this `(int)items.First()`

Comment: @HariPrasad, object does not contain definition about items.First()

Comment: Try using this `foreach (object[] items in repo.ExecuteReader())`.

Comment: Oh, nice one, that works with items.First() and now with cast (int)items[0]

Comment: I'm glad it fixed your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is provided by **Hari Prasad**, just need to change from

```
   foreach (var items in repo.ExecuteReader()) {}
```

to

```
   foreach (var object[] items in repo.ExecuteReader()
```

Now indexing and cast are working

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlDataReader reader = repo.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.reas.Read()) {
       rss.Id = (int)reader[0]; // should work
```

UPDATE

Try this

---

The result of `ExecuteReader()` **method must be unboxed** (looks like a cast, but this is unboxing) to the correct Type, before it can be assigned to an  object or variable.

[Are you asking why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111857/why-do-we-need-boxing-and-unboxing-in-c)

Comment: It says that: "cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'"

Answer (score 1):

Try to cast it first, see below:

```
foreach (var items in repo.ExecuteReader()
   {
        var obj[] = (object[])items;
        rss.Id = obj[0];
        yield return obj;
   }
```