# Boxing and UnBoxing from List to Object in C#

Tags: c#, .net, object, value-type, boxing

I wish to know my approach is right or wrong ?

Refer the two statements

**Case: #1**

```
List<string> person = new List<string>() {
                            "Harry"
                            "Emma"
                            "Watson"
                        }
```

**Case: #2**

```
Object person = new List<string>() {
                            "Harry"
                            "Emma"
                            "Watson"
                        }
```

Let me know

which statement is **boxing** and which statement is **un-boxing** ?

Both statements are **equal and identical** ???

Comment: There's no boxing in either case here. Your code doesn't include any value types at all. The statements aren't identical though - one declares a variable of type `List<string>` and the other declares a variable of type `Object`... that affects how you can use the variable later.

Comment: `List<T>` is a `class`, not `struct`, so there's no boxing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of them.
Boxing and unboxing is a mechanism provided to handle value types with unified type system in .NET.

for example:

```
int i = 4;
object o = i; //boxing, int is boxed in an object
int j = (int)o; //unboxing, an int is unboxed from an object
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx):
[image]

Read more about [why we need boxing and unboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111857/why-do-we-need-boxing-and-unboxing-in-c).

There is a special case in boxing of nullable types.
When a nullable type boxes, it boxes as its value or null. You can not have a nullable value boxed.

```
int? a = 4;
object o = a; //boxing, o is a boxed int now
Console.WriteLine(o.GetType()); //System.Int32
int? b = null;
o = b; //boxing, o is null
Console.WriteLine(o.GetType()); // NullReferenceException
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no boxing because List is a reference type:

> Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type object or
>   to any interface type implemented by this value type
>
> Unboxing extracts the value type from the object. Boxing is implicit;
>   unboxing is explicit. The concept of boxing and unboxing underlies the
>   C# unified view of the type system in which a value of any type can be
>   treated as an object.

Read More : [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)

This is boxing:

```
int i = 123;
// The following line boxes i.
object o = i;
```

This is unboxing:

```
o = 123;
i = (int)o;  // unboxing
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not an boxing or unboxing.

Boxing means that you store the `value type` into `the reference type`, and the unboxing is the reverse of `boxing`.

In your examples both List and Object are `reference type`.You are only playing with references

```
int i = 123;
// The following line boxes i.
object o = i;  

o = 123;
i = (int)o;  // unboxing

int -> object boxing

object -> int unboxing
```

For more see here [Boxing and Unboxing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)