# Var or Dynamic variables reference type or value type?

Tags: c#, .net

We can assign var and dynamic to any data type, so where are these stored in memory? var is resolved at compile time, my understanding is  var are stored in heap or stack depending on the assignment. But dynamic is resolved at runtime so before that where are they stored?

Comment: Any answer you get is going to be an [implemention detail](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`var` is merely syntactic sugar for variable declarations. There's no functional difference between `var str = "abc";` and `string str = "abc";`, so whether it goes on the stack or the heap depends on the type you are working with.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx

`dynamic` incorporates a bunch of stuff under the hood but is ultimately treated similarly to `object`, so it would be a reference type which puts it on the heap.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

Answer (score 3):

As you say, the `var` keyword has no significance to the run time. It is a language detail that is swapped out by the compiler for an inferred type.

`dynamic` objects are always [boxed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111857/why-do-we-need-boxing-and-unboxing-in-c) to behave as references, even if the actual type is a value type such as an `int`.

You can conclude that variable declared as dynamic will always behave as a reference. The reference itself will belong to the scope in which it was created (locals on stack, members on heap) but the object it references will be stored in heap memory.