# Overriding C# variable in derived class with different data type

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

My base class declares:

```
public double Value;
```

My derived class declares:

```
public new decimal Value;
```

In the tip to use the `new` keyword, it says: "`...Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.`".

This explanation doesn't seem correct. When using the `new` keyword, it is not hiding the base variable. It keeps both variables with the same name, and even with different values.

I understand there is a design issue on my side, but I'd like to know why the `new` keyword doesn't *really* hide the base class variable. Also, why the `new` keyword is even available if it would mean a design issue (changing data type in the derived class). Is using `dynamic` an option here?
The issue is: for most part, `double` is fine. However in a few derived classes, it must be `decimal`.

This question is focused on the use of the `new` keyword for variables in derived classes, not really a discussion of differences between double and decimal.

Thank you.

Comment: Both variables are there. If you say `var der=new Derived();` then `der.Value` will be `decimal`. However,  `((Base)der).Value` will be `double`. An instance of a subclass is *always* an instance of its base class, so the base class member must be there. What the `new` keyword does is say that in the context of the derived class, `Value` has a *new* meaning compared to the meaning in the context of the base class

Comment: OP,. one question you could ask yourself is, what exactly is the variable hidden *from*? When you are able to answer that question correctly then I think the answer to your post will be obvious.

Answer (score 5):

You mixed the concepts about (`new`, `override`) and (`property`, `field`).

I'll provide some information about them and provide my suggestion.
My suggestion is on the 3rd part.

If this post doesn't answer your question, please edit your post with use case.

---

### `new` is not `override`

`new` is to "hide" base class's property/field, which is NOT overriding `virtual` functions.

To sum up:

1. `override` is used when base class' `virtual` function need to be altered or `abstract` function need to be defined.

If child class calls a function `foo` of base class which calls a virtual function `bar`, the CHILD version of `bar` would be called, not base version.

2. For `new`,

If a child class calls a function `foo` of base class which calls a function `bar`, the BASE version of `bar` would be called, not child version.

I rarely use new, so can't suggest about how to use it.

Ref [Difference between new and override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399127/difference-between-new-and-override)

---

### You cannot override a Field.

```
public class foo
{
    public double field; // This is field
    public int property  // This is property
    {
        get{ return 1  };
    }
}
```

1. Property is a wrapper of get/set functions.
2. Property could be overridden (because of #1), but fields could not be overridden.

Ref [What is the difference between a field and a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property)

---

### Suggestion

What I come to mind is to implement `Value` as an `object` property

```
public class foo
{
    public virtual object Value
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

Then wrapping it to desired type, but this would cost [box and unboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2111905/4123703).

However if your case is not performance critical, it should be okay.

```
public class bar : foo
{
    public override object Value
    {
        get{ // something different
        }; 
        set{ // something different
        };
    }

    public double DesiredValue
    {
        get{  return (double)Value };
    }
}
```

Comment: Since in this case we are dealing with Double (8 bytes) and Decimal (16 bytes) should we also consider the memory / CPU trade-off of just storing them all as Decimal and truncating it as a Double as needed? I assume this would be faster than boxing and unboxing.

Comment: @Origin I can't answer your question easily, because it depends on context. If box/unboxing frequently occur, I'd say profile it and see if performance increases. Also memory usage of the machine might be concerned in resource limited case....